# Make custom field on product page required

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have added a simple input field just below the short description on a product page. But can't seem to figure out how to make it a required field, so that you can't add the product to cart unless this field is filled out. Adding required to the input field isn't enough.

```
<label>Enter ID: <input name="_custom_option" value="" required></label>
```

using this code to create the field

```
function mic_custom_option() {
global $product;
$id = $product->get_id();
if ($id==14352){
    $value = isset( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) : '';
    printf( '<p><label>%s<input name="_custom_option" value="" class="form-control" id="_custom_option" required" /></label></p>', __( 'Enter ID: ', 'www-plugin-textdomain' ), esc_attr( $value ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'mic_custom_option', 9 );
```

Comment: Could you please add a tag indicating the programming language(s) relevant to your question?

Comment: Please paste the whole PHP code you used to print this field, so that I can find out if it's inside the add to cart form or not. Also, please set the field to just "required" e.g. <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>

Answer (score 1):

As your code you can use

```
<label>Enter ID: <input name="_custom_option" value="" required></label>
```

or

```
<label>Enter ID: <input name="_custom_option" value="" required="required"></label>
```

Comment: Implicit labels are not recommended - don't wrap inputs with labels and use "for" and "id" attributes instead e.g. https://css-tricks.com/html-inputs-and-labels-a-love-story/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your HTML markup is broken.
You can use templates from here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/overview/

Secondly, you must replace the **required=""** with a **required**:

```
<input name="_custom_option" type="text" class="form-control" id="_custom_option" required>
```

Here is my working example with your code:
https://jsfiddle.net/SergeyKozlov/ebn40tqx/

[image: image do here]